# changing ajax from get to post

Tags: jquery, post

Here is my original ajax query:

```
 var url = ajaxPath+ "?s=search&r="+resource+"&q="+query;
 $.getJSON(url,function(data){
```

Here is my updated query:

```
$.getJSON(ajaxPath,{s:"search",r:resource,q:query},function(data){
```

The updated one is not working for some reason. any ideas why?

Comment: What does it mean "does not work"? Does it return 404? Or just bad response? Is your code on the server side ready for POST?

Comment: did you see any error in console ? did you check if any call is actually fired (or) if the server is returning proper response in DevTools -> Network ?

Answer (score 2):

No where in your example are you specifying `POST` so `GET` will be used as default.

That $.getJSON() function get's converted to this, this is what I prefer as it is very clear:

```
$.ajax({
 dataType: "json",
 type: "POST",
 url: url,
data: data,
success: function(result,status,xhr){
 }
});
```

data would obviously be in the form of a `JSON` object.

Comment: Small correction, type will always be `GET` for $.getJSON() even when you pass a `data` object. All the properties of data object are implicitly converted into query string params before firing the Ajax call